# Laravel Mail SSL Error

Tags: php, email, ssl, laravel-5

while working on my current project, I already started to experience problems after trying to implement the Password Reset function based on the scaffolding that Laravel provides.
Currently, I am only using the default routes and controllers for the password reset procedure.

When it came to testing that functionality, I got the following error:
`stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1`

I checked my mail server and I saw that I hadn't yet implemented the new Certificate from Let's Encrypt but was still using a self-signed one. After fixing that issue and also taking care of the intermediate certificate for the Lets Encrypt CA, I checked my server with this tool: https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/mail.dream-code.eu

This clearly states, that my server is not having any SSL issues anymore, but still, I receive the same message from Laravel when I try to use the Mail function. Is there any known issue about this or do I have to take further steps?

I found something about Laravel 4.2 where you had to change the mail provider from `smtp`to `mail` which had fixed the issue for some people but this was also not successful. When I used that mail provider, there was no error but I also did not receive an E-Mail. Neither in the default folder, nor in the spam folder.

When I "manually" send mails via Thunderbird from the same address that is set for Laravel, there is no problem, the E-Mail arrives just a few seconds after sending.

Just in case it's somehow relevant, I try to send to a gmail address. The mail server is a Dovecot/Postfix Combo with the already mentioned Let's Encrypt certificate. PTR Record is configured correctly.

Comment: you can turn it off if you wanted to by using the following in you .env

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

Comment: I know right, but I don't want to turn of Encryption if possible. There must be a way to make it work.

Comment: make sure your server is using the new certs, i remember running across this and in the end the server wasn't actually using the new certs.  I know that's not much help but i can only vaguely remember my fix in laravel for this. Sorry

Comment: Yeah that was also my clue, but I double-checked again. The link in my first post also confirms, that the SSL Config should be fine.